# React: How do I use values from an object's specific key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and am trying to figure out how to return a particular objects entry by it's key.

So far, I have an object as such:

```
const questions = [
  {
    id: '1',
    section: 's1',
    answers: [
      "answer a",
      "answer b",
      "answer c",
      "answer d",
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Question 2',
    answers: [
      "answer a",
      "answer b",
      "answer c",
      "answer d",
    ]
  },
  //etc
```

which I am currently iterating through and using parts of as props in a component, eg:

```
  return (
    <div>
      {questions.map((question) => (
        <Question
          key={question.id}
          questionNum={question.id}
          title={question.title}
          answers={question.answers}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

This works fine and as expected.

But now I need to modify this so it only returns the values of 1 given particular key in the object.

I've been searching and experimenting with `.get()` but to be honest I'm really stumped with how to do this.

Would anyone know the best way to approach this?

Comment: `const someObj = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: ['someArray'] };` <-- Consider this object. Now, `someObj.key1` will get us `value1`. And, `someObj.key3[0]` will get us `someArray`. In your example, `questions[0].id` will get the value `1`. While `questions[1].title` will get `Question 2`. So on & so forth.

Comment: The question is unclear, from which function do you want to return the value of a specific key? If you only want to return one key from the map callback function, you can use object destructuring, `questions.map(({title})=>{<Question title={title} />})`

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you'd just need to filter the questions by changing `questions.map` to `questions.filter(q => q.id === 1).map` to get the question with ID 1 for example.

Comment: @user2740650 yep, thats what I was after. Want to make that an answer?

Comment: Looks like someone did!  Note that it may not be very efficient, but if your array of questions isn't very big, it won't matter much.  It would be better to put them into a Map where the key is the ID you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` the `questions` by a particular key of the object first and then do the `map`. Let's say `id` with value 1.

```
return (
    <div>
        {questions
            .filter(({ id }) => id === "1")
            .map(question => (
                <Question
                    key={question.id}
                    questionNum={question.id}
                    title={question.title}
                    answers={question.answers}
                />
            ))}
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, I guess you can do the same using `map` itself

Assume you have the below array

```
const questions = [
  {
    id: '1',
    section: 's1',
    answers: [
      "answer a",
      "answer b",
      "answer c",
      "answer d",
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Question 2',
    answers: [
      "answer a",
      "answer b",
      "answer c",
      "answer d",
    ]
  }]
```

and now you wanna just pull out the `answers` key alone then you can do something like

```
const result = questions.map((question) => {answers: question.answers}); // where the specific key here is answers
```